# Timeout for grep in bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I need to grep for a specific string in a specific time on an input:

```
trap "kill 0" EXIT SIGINT SIGTERM
RESULT=$(adb logcat MyTag:V *:S | grep -m 1 "Hello World") &
sleep 10
if [ "$RESULT" = "" ]; then
    echo "Timeout!"
else
    echo "found"
fi
```

with the trap the subshell gets killed correctly but i see that the grep does not work anymore now. `adb logcat` is the only process running in the subshell, when executing the script

Comment: sorry, in the real script i use the ouput of adb logcat, not of cat. that was just a short test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open a file descriptor as input with process substitution. After n seconds you could read the result.

```
{
    sleep 10
    IFS= read -rd '' -u 4 RESULT
    if [ "$RESULT" = "" ]; then
        echo "Timeout!"
    else
        echo "found"
    fi
} 4< <(adb logcat MyTag:V *:S | grep -m 1 "Hello World")
```

You could also use `exec` to keep it not just within `{}`.

Although I still wonder why you have to place the command in the background and use sleep to wait for it. It runs with a subshell so the value saved in RESULT would always be lost.

```
RESULT=$(adb logcat MyTag:V *:S | grep -m 1 "Hello World") &
sleep 10

RESULT=$(adb logcat MyTag:V *:S | grep -m 1 "Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you kill the subshell using `$!` (the pid of the last process invoked)

Comment: thanks! i found the error with the subshell but now grep isnt working anymore.